# Resizing the header on scroll works well in safari but gets choppy on chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, firefox

I want my header to smoothly shrink as you scroll, and although it works perfectly in Safari, it's pretty choppy in Chrome and Firefox.

**JavaScript:**

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() < 35) {
        $('#header').removeClass('tiny');
    } else {
        $('#header').addClass('tiny');
    }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.tete {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top:0;
    height:200px;
    width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    z-index: 1000;
    transition: all 500ms;
}

.tete.tiny {
    margin-top:-80px;
}
```

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pampam/5W7pa/1/) link with most of the `html/css/js`

The jsfiddle works well in Safari but not in Chrome or Firefox. I just updated my browsers, so I don't think it's an update issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are animating the top margin, you need to tell the browser where to start animating from, which is zero. So, you need:

```
.tete {
    margin-top:0;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kthornbloom/5W7pa/2/

You should also prefix the transitions like:

```
    transition: all 500ms;
    -o-transition: all 500ms;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
```

You don't actually need all of them, but doing this should cover old, current, and future browsers.